# TFS 2010/Msbuild fails, StackOverFlowException

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build, automation

I'm having trouble with an upgraded 2008 build. I'm using the Upgrade template.

Everything builds fine, but when I get to `GetImpactedTests` it crashes.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Can I turn off `GetImpactedTests`? Can't find a property for it.

```
TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '255'.
```

From the build log:

```
CoreGetChangesetsAndUpdateWorkItems:
  TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://ourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/23071"
  Analyzing labels Release_2.3.10301.14 and Release_2.3.10302.2.
GetImpactedTests:
  TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://ourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/23071"
```

From the event log:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
Fault offset: 0x00000000000536ba
Faulting process id: 0xd14
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb772eb97a8234
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 2cb88eb5-e323-11df-8d1d-0050568d001c
```

Answer (score 5):

I added /p:PerformTestImpactAnalysis=false for now, and it works